# How to set a dropdown list data source to an Enum

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

```
public enum SampleEnum
{
    Room1 = 1,
    Room2 = 2,
    Room3 = 3
}
```

I have the above sample C# Enum which I want to set as a data source to an ASP .NET dropdown list like below

```
private void PopulateMyList()
{
    ddlRoom.ClearSelection();
    ddlRoom.Items.Clear();
    ddlRoom.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
    ddlRoom.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select...", ""));
    ddlRoom.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(SampleEnum));
    ddlRoom.DataBind();
}
```

The problem I am having with the above implementation is that values Room1 or Room2 or Room3 are set as both the dropdown list SelectedValue and SelectedItem.

How can bind this enum to the dropdown list such that if I select

> Room2

, the selectedValue becomes

> 2

Comment: Is this WebForms? If so, why are you using WebForms in 2022?

Comment: [Strategies for migrating ASP.NET Web Forms apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/porting-existing-aspnet-apps/migrate-web-forms) :)

Comment: @Dai Its a legacy  business webforms app that is heavily is use and unfortunately has to be supported.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of filling the `DropDownList` with `string`s, you fill it with the `SampleEnum`s directly.

```cs
ddlRoom.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SampleEnum));
```

When you get the selected item for instance you will get the enum, not the string, fixing one of your problems.

The other problem (showing the enums name, not value) is solved in the `DropDownList` implementation. As you can set any `object` as `DataSource`, the DDL will call `ToString` on these `object`s to have a display label (how would it get any string to display from an object otherwise?).

The `ToString` method in `Enum`s is implemented so, that it's name and not value is returned as string, thus the name will be shown in the DDL.